# Format numbers to be 00:00 using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I have created a working [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BxX9x5zYFMXVqt5JsN1F?p=preview) which allows you to incrementally add and subtract minutes from a time. However the time is a simple string '15' which is piped through a filter to put out '15min'. I would like to change this so instead of '15min' is said '00:15' how could I rework the hourMinFilter to be a timeFilter?

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.readyTime = 15;
});

app.filter('hourMinFilter', function () {
    return function (value, max) {
      if (value == max) return 'All';
      var h = parseInt(value / 60);
      var m = parseInt(value % 60);
      var hStr = (h > 0) ? h + 'hr'  : '';
      var mStr = (m > 0) ? m + 'min' : '';
      var glue = (hStr && mStr) ? ' ' : '';
      return hStr + glue + mStr;
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest trying to play around with the existing code. You basically just have to do tests to the result and insert the missing zeroes.

If you are impatient, here is a suggested solution:

http://plnkr.co/edit/aDIDUV7r2YpqnuuShIi0?p=preview

Changed three lines:

```
  var hStr = (h > 0) ? h + 'hr'  : '';
  var mStr = (m > 0) ? m + 'min' : '';
  var glue = (hStr && mStr) ? ' ' : ''
```

to

```
  var hStr = (h > 0) ? h >= 10 ? h  : '0' + h : '00';
  var mStr = (m > 0) ? m >= 10 ? m  : '0' + m : '00';
  var glue = (hStr && mStr) ? ':' : '';
```

Comment: I got part way there just before you posted the answer, I had it going 2:15 and I didn't know how to make it 02:15 so your answer was perfect! Really appreciate it, cheers!